# Conversion of string into datetime in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, type-conversion, dataframe

I have a column in pandas dataframe in the format `20151028 193133` 
I want to convert this string into a date time format like `2015-10-28 19:26:48`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and parameter `format` [docs](http://strftime.org/):

```
print df   
               col
0  20151028 193133
1  20151028 193133
2  20151028 193133

df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
print df
                  col
0 2015-10-28 19:31:33
1 2015-10-28 19:31:33
2 2015-10-28 19:31:33
```

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but I have got another error yet again ValueError: time data '20151028 13' does not match format '%Y%m%d %H%M%S'

Comment: I have the complete data. The format field doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Solved the issue. Pandas was eliminating some of the leading zeros. Thanks